# Windows AD domain - Server 2008 level - How to forward DNS requests for a single subdomain only to an external DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, active-directory

Internally, our AD domain is contoso.com, and our internal DNS servers present that domain authoritatively.

We're at Server 2008 forest/domain level.

Externally, contoso.com is a domain owned and registered by us that is registered with an external DNS provider.

Internally, we'd like to forward requests for subdomain.contoso.com to the external DNS provider.

I tried to set up a conditional forwarder for this but got the highly useful error message "A problem occurred while trying to add the conditional forwarder.  A zone configuration problem occurred."

I read elsewhere this is because our DNS presents the contoso.com domain authoritatively... in order to resolve this we'd need to forward requests for that to this provider, which unfortunately is not an option.

Is there a way we can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is a subdomain of your AD domain you can't use a conditional forwarder. What you can do is to configure a delegation of the subdomain to the external DNS servers.

Right click your AD DNS zone and select **New Delegation** and follow the prompts.

Comment: Glad to help...